# context is slow or being called twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have an issue with the Context I am using for my auth. If I console.log when logged in, first I get false, and then a second later it logs again with the token etc. So, something is wrong with my code.

Here is my auth hook:

```
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

export const useAuth = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(false);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(false);

  const login = useCallback((uid, token) => {
    setToken(token);
    setUserId(uid);
    localStorage.setItem(
      "userData",
      JSON.stringify({
        userId: uid,
        token: token,
      })
    );
  }, []);

  const logout = useCallback(() => {
    setToken(null);
    setUserId(null);
    localStorage.removeItem("userData");
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
    if (storedData && storedData.token) {
      login(storedData.userId, storedData.token);
    }
  }, [login]);

  return { token, login, logout, userId };
};
```

The auth context:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  userId: null,
  token: null,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {},
});
```

Example of the component where I have the issue (basically in all components I am using this auth context)

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import AdminCard from "../components/adminCards/AdminCard";
import { AuthContext } from "../../shared/context/auth-context";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(auth);
  return (
    <div className="admin-wrapper">
      <div className="main-panel">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="col-3">
              <AdminCard title="Contact Enquiries" />
              <AdminCard title="Card 2" />
              <AdminCard title="Card 3" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

In console I first see 'false' and then a second later I see the contents of 'auth'.

Example of App.js

```
const App = () => {
   const { token, login, logout, userId } = useAuth();
  return (
    <>
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          isLoggedIn: !!token,
          token: token,
          userId: userId,
          login: login,
          logout: logout,
        }}
      >
 <Router>
<Switch>
   <Route path="/" exact>
    <Dashboard />
   </Route>
</Switch>
</Router>
</AuthContext.Provider>
</>
};

export default App;
```

An example of the issue is if I log in and navigate to the dashboard via clicking on a link I have no problem. If I am on the dashboard and I refresh the browser, I get a 403 error and the request fails because the token was not available yet when sending the request.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getItems = async () => {
      const config = {
        method: "get",
        url: "http://localhost:8000/api/admin/somedata",
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token },
      };
      const responseData = await Axios(config);
      setItems(responseData.data);
      console.log(responseData.data);
    };
    getItems();
  }, []);
```

To clarify, I only have this issue if I refresh the browser.

Comment: I don't see where you're using `auth` from `useContext(AuthContext)` or where you have `AuthContext.Provider` in the component tree. If you don't have code for both of those things, that's definitely causing your problem; if you do have the code, please post it in as simplified of a form as possible.

Comment: React re-renders on changes. You set loggedIn to `false` for the initial render. Login will re-render the required context and child components. That's just how react works and does not mean its slow.

Comment: @JoshWilson, added a quick example of my App.js for you to see

Comment: @Andre, the problem is that when I try make a get request in the protected admin area it fails initially because I have to send the token in the headers but because the token is not there on first load, it fails. This is my problem with the first console.log being false and then only a second later do I see the token in console. I want to see it there on the first console.log and don't want it to load twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can streamline your `useAuth` hook a bit so that it immediately returns a result not just on rerender.

```
export const useAuth = () => {
  const [{
    // normalize undefined -> null
    userId = null,
    token = null
  // init state from localStorage
  }, setUserData] = useState(() => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData") || "{}"));

  // only update the context if userId or token changed
  return useMemo(() => {
    if (userId || token) {
      localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify({ userId, token }));
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem("userData");
    }

    // There's no point of putting these functions into useCallback, 
    // unless you use them somewhere as deps.

    // TODO: validate login? disable login while logged in?
    const login = (userId, token) => setUserData({ userId, token });
    const logout = () => setUserData({});

    return {
      userId,
      token,
      isLoggedIn: !!token,
      login,
      logout
    };
  }, [userId, token]);
};
```

then App becomes

```
const App = () => {
  const authContext = useAuth();
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then, your `useEffect` clearly depends on the token; at least its existance. You need to put it in the `deps`.

At least like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getItems = async () => {
    const config = {
      method: "get",
      url: "http://localhost:8000/api/admin/somedata",
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token },
    };
    const responseData = await Axios(config);
    setItems(responseData.data);
    console.log(responseData.data);
  };
  auth.token && getItems();
}, [!!auth.token]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is React itself. What you can do is that you can use an useEffect hook as following,

```
useEffect(() => {
  auth && doSomethingWithAuth(auth);
}, [auth])
```

However, the ideal solution would be showing some loading component while your auth token is being read. You can basically extract your provider to be another component. Then you can try to read your auth variable in your provider component. While starting the reading operation, set a state as authLoading and set it as false when the auth change to be truthy (with an useEffect hook again).Finally, if authLoading === true, show some loading component/text, else show the children of the provider.

Hope this helps!